# I'm trying to use Block Syntax but it doesn't work

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I'm learning Block Syntax but something goes wrong.

The first code is below:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D centerCoordinate = [Location sharedManager].coordinate;
MKCoordinateSpan span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01, 0.01);
MKCoordinateRegion coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(centerCoordinate, span);
[self.mapView setRegion:coordinateRegion animated:YES];
```

The below code (my first try) worked:

```
MKCoordinateRegion (^aRegion)() = ^(void)
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D centerCoordinate = [Location sharedManager].coordinate;
    MKCoordinateSpan span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01, 0.01);
    return MKCoordinateRegionMake(centerCoordinate, span);
};
[self.mapView setRegion:aRegion() animated:YES];
```

But the below code (my second try) doesn't work:

```
[self.mapView setRegion:(MKCoordinateRegion^(void)){
    CLLocationCoordinate2D centerCoordinate = [Location sharedManager].coordinate;
    MKCoordinateSpan span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01, 0.01);
    return MKCoordinateRegionMake(centerCoordinate, span);
}];
```

The error message is below:

```
1. Block pointer to non-function type is invalid.
2. Unexpected type name 'CLLocationCoordinate2D': expected expression
```

[image]

How can I work this code? Thank you for your kindness.

Comment: blocks are primarily meant for call backs. In your case its not the proper use of blocks. What you can do is define your block outside like u have done already and call that block from the method i.e 
[self.mapView setRegion: aRegion()];

Comment: @RatikantaPatra I don't agree that block are made for call back. Ya we use it as call back most but it is perfect to use for other purpose. Because if block are only for call back than why it have return type! But the main question is why he is not able to make use of it? What mistake is done in code?

Comment: It looks to me like the code that works actually executes the block and the block's return result is the parameter passed to setRegion: where the second attempt passes the block itself as a parameter to setRegion:, which is of course expecting an MKCoordinateRegion as its parameter, not a block. Why do you want to use a block in this case and not a method, and why do you prefer to make it anonymous?

Comment: @CRDave I agree. That's why I said they are primarily used for call backs. The mistake here is that the block that he is using is the definition/body of the block and the value will be returned to the caller. In this case the method is not the caller, it only provides definition/body to the block

Comment: I am just learning Block and I just tried to apply the Block to the existing code. There is no intention to let the code better.

Comment: @Ratikanta The first and second code works but the third doesn't work.

Comment: As @RobP said: In the first try the block is *evaluated* (`aRegion()`) and the result passed as an argument. In your second try, the *block itself* is passed as an argument which causes the errors. You can fix it by inserting `()` at the right place to evaluate the block, something like `[self.mapView setRegion:(MKCoordinateRegion^(void)){ ... }()];`

Comment: @weed third won't work as its not proper. Will update my answer.

Comment: @Ratikanta's answer does work.

Comment: @RobP's answer doesn't work.

Comment: could you specify how either one didn't work for you? what was the failure or message? thx

Comment: @RatikantaPatra's answer did not really address how you can still use a block, but do so anonymously and inline without declaring and naming it first. That's what you *were* trying to do in the second example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case the method provides the body to the block. So the returned value(MKCoordinateRegionMake) will be returned to the caller of the block, which is not present.(setRegion: is not the caller here).

What you can do instead is you can do this:

```
MKCoordinateRegion (^aRegion)() = ^(void)
{
   CLLocationCoordinate2D centerCoordinate = [Location sharedManager].coordinate;
   MKCoordinateSpan span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01, 0.01);
   return MKCoordinateRegionMake(centerCoordinate, span);
};
   [self.mapView setRegion:aRegion() animated:YES];
```

Moreover if you still want a block-style execution you can try this:

```
[self.mapView setRegion:({
    CLLocationCoordinate2D centerCoordinate = [Location sharedManager].coordinate;
    MKCoordinateSpan span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01, 0.01);
    MKCoordinateRegion region= MKCoordinateRegionMake(centerCoordinate, span);
    region;
})];
```

The second one is not a block but its a syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Let's make an answer out of these good comments:

It looks to me like the code that works actually executes the block and the block's return result is the parameter passed to setRegion: where the second attempt passes the block itself as a parameter to setRegion:, which is of course expecting an MKCoordinateRegion as its parameter, not a block.

And (credit to MartinR), you can force evaluation of the block with an extra set of parentheses:

EDIT I'll get this right eventually

```
[self.mapView setRegion:^MKCoordinateRegion(void){
    CLLocationCoordinate2D centerCoordinate = [Location sharedManager].coordinate;
    MKCoordinateSpan span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01, 0.01);
    return MKCoordinateRegionMake(centerCoordinate, span);
}()];
```

Comment: I fixed a typo. Better now.

Comment: Your first version of the answer was almost correct, but there was another error in the block definition. It should be `[self.mapView setRegion:^MKCoordinateRegion(void)){ ... }()];`. The second version of your answer is something completely different: a *compound statement expression* (as in the other answer). That works as well but has nothing to do with Objective-C blocks.

Comment: I got confused there for a second... I *thought* () after the block was closer tothe right way to execute (similar to JavaScript) but had to go re-check the Apple guide on blocks. Thanks!